# How do I receive data from JSON/gSON Object with jqGrid?

Tags: json, jqgrid, gson, jsonreader

i'm trying to add data from an Java Object via gSON over JSON to a jqGRID Table but i'm stuck, configuring the jsonreader.

The Java Object looks like this:

```
public class UserObject {
    public int uid = 1337;

    public List<String> data1= new ArrayList<String>(){
    {
            add("some");
            add("new");
            add("data");
        }
    };

    public List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(){
    {
            add("another");
            add("list");
            add("with");
            add("some");
            add("strings");
            add("in");
                    add("it");
        }
    };
```

This Object will be encoded via gSON and sent via JSON to a Client, using jqGRID. I ONLY want to show all items from "list2"... no IDs, no Counter, nothing..

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Update: since noone has an answer, i wrote a wrapper-class so handle the json data and convert it into jqgrid-usable data...